# Set width to 100 percent of text plus padding

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting the code below to style correctly. What I need is to have the labels be 100% width of the text inside (no word wrap) plus a fixed padding on the left and right sides. I can set a manual width using pixels but then all buttons are exactly the same width, which is not what I want. I have searched for the answer and have come up empty handed. All the solutions I tried did not work for me.

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzYEbv

HTML:

```
<div id="toolbar-upper">
<div class="sort-by-container">
  <span>SORT BY </span>
  <ul class="sort-by-radios">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="newest" name="sortby" value="" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
      <label for="newest">Newest Arrivals</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="name" name="sortby" value="" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="price-high" name="sortby" value="" checked="checked" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
      <label for="price-high">Price (High)</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="price-low" name="sortby" value="" checked="checked" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
      <label for="price-low">Price (Low)</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#toolbar-upper .sort-by-radios {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}

#toolbar-upper .sort-by-radios li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
}

#toolbar-upper .sort-by-radios label, #toolbar-upper .sort-by-radios input {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

#toolbar-upper .sort-by-radios input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0.01;
    z-index: 100;
}

#toolbar-upper .sort-by-radios input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: #3c8dc5;
    color: white;
}

#toolbar-upper .sort-by-radios label {
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    border: 1px solid #4C4C4C;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 90;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
}

#toolbar-upper .sort-by-radios label:hover {
    background:#3c8dc5;
    color: white;
}

#toolbar-upper .sort-by-container span {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you need? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXVzVx If it is, I'll make an answer with it.

Comment: @FaustoNA Yes sir!! Perfect thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXVzVx

Here's what you need. The problem was `position:absolute;` on the label items. I removed it, and added `white-space:nowrap;` to the label text, and modified the padding a little bit.

If you want to maintain `position:absolute;` on the rest of the elements:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNmJQj

ProTip: you can go `padding: 5px 30px;` and it means the same as `padding:5px 30px 5px 30px;`

Comment: Is there a way to maintain the absolute positioning?

Comment: I'll check it out. What's the purpose though? I don't understand why you used it in the first place.

Comment: I just got it. The purpose was to keep the radio button behind the label. If I remove absolute then is bumps the label down and the radio is above. To fix it I added the wordwrap, set the label to position relative and then removed the fixed width. If you update your answer I will give you the points

Comment: You can go with something like `input[type="radio"]:checked{visibility:hidden;}` for that